# SQL Query to return multiple key value pairs from a single table in one row

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a single table of key value pairs for multiple components. Each type of component can have different attributes (keys), although each type will always have the same attributes.

For example:

```
-----------------------------------
| Comp_ID | KeyField | ValueField |
-----------------------------------
|  A      | Size     | Big        |
|  A      | Weight   | 10         |
|  A      | Colour   | Green      |
|  B      | Length   | Short      |
|  B      | Density  | 1.5        |
|  B      | Colour   | Yellow     |
|  B      | Radius   | 3          |
|  C      | Size     | Small      |
|  C      | Weight   | 20         |
|  C      | Colour   | Red        |
|  D      | Size     | Small      |
|  D      | Weight   | 20         |
|  D      | Colour   | Blue       |
```

A, C and D are all the same type of component while B is different.

How can I do the following:

1. Select only the components with a certain attribute (key). Eg: only components with the size key.
2. Display this with one row per component ID.

Based on the above example I would expect a table like this:

```
-------------------------------------
| Comp_ID | Size  | Weight | Colour |
-------------------------------------
|  A      | Big   | 10     | Green  |
|  C      | Small | 20     | Red    |
|  D      | Small | 20     | Blue   |
```

I am querying an oracle database if that matters but hopefully answers will be generic SQL - the simpler the better:)

Edit: I realise this is not the best way to store the data but this is beyond my control - This is a vendor solution from GE and (obviously) can't be changed. I Just need to query the data.

Comment: Possible duplicated question with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41003587/how-to-select-2-table-like-this/41003777?noredirect=1#comment69217373_41003777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use conditional aggregation. You can also use a `WHERE EXISTS` in order to exclude records that don't contain 'Size'.

Please note, I've changed the field names slightly, you really shouldn't use reserved words as your field names.

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (Comp_ID varchar(1), KeyField varchar(7), ValueField varchar(6))
INSERT INTO #TestData (Comp_ID, KeyField, ValueField)
VALUES
 ('A','Size','Big')
,('A','Weight','10')
,('A','Colour','Green')
,('B','Length','Short')
,('B','Density','1.5')
,('B','Colour','Yellow')
,('B','Radius','3')
,('C','Size','Small')
,('C','Weight','20')
,('C','Colour','Red')
,('D','Size','Small')
,('D','Weight','20')
,('D','Colour','Blue')
```

Query

```
SELECT td.Comp_ID,
       Max(CASE WHEN td.KeyField = 'Size' THEN td.ValueField END) as Size, 
       Max(CASE WHEN td.KeyField = 'Weight' THEN td.ValueField END) as Weight,
       Max(CASE WHEN td.KeyField = 'Colour' THEN td.ValueField END) as Colour
FROM   #TestData td
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #TestData td2 WHERE td2.KeyField = 'Size' AND td.Comp_ID = td2.Comp_ID)
GROUP  BY Comp_ID
```

Output

```
Comp_ID Size    Weight  Colour
A       Big     10      Green
C       Small   20      Red
D       Small   20      Blue
```

Notice that `Comp_ID` B doesn't appear because it doesn't have a 'Size' entry.

Comment: Thanks @Rich... Marked as the answer as this satisfies both requirements.

Comment: I've also updated the question to use KeyField and ValueField like you have suggested:)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using Conditional Aggregate

```
SELECT Comp_ID,
       Max(CASE WHEN KEY = 'Size' THEN value END) as Size, 
       Max(CASE WHEN KEY = 'Weight' THEN value END) as Weight,
       Max(CASE WHEN KEY = 'Colour' THEN value END) as Colour
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY Comp_ID
```

If `Comp_ID` can have more than one record for same key then you need to replace the aggregate(`Max`) based on your requirement

It is not the right way to store your data, consider changing your table structure. It is better to have separate table for each `Key`.

Comment: I realise this is not a great way to store this data but this is beyond my control. I just need to query the data...